# How to send variables from a running python script to a running AHK script?

Tags: python, autohotkey

I have seen some questions and answers about running a python script with arguments from AHK, what I'm trying to do is kinda the opposite.

One solution would be to set values for the clipboard inside python, and then read them in AHK. Only problem is that it scrambles the clipboard.

Another solution would be to write a text file in python, and then read it in AHK, but I'm
anticipating that to be high latency if the computer is busy with other processes - I need a solution that takes 30 milliseconds or less.

Comment: you can save the current state of the clipboard, edit the clipboard, read the clipboard from ahk, then rewrite the clipboard to its original state (the only way i would know how to do that is to just wait 500ms or so before rewriting to the clipboard). the best way is probably writing to a file, try that and see what the speeds are like

Comment: This should help you.

[link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/OnMessage.htm#SendString)

Comment: Or this [link](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6148)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you use AHK to launch the python script and then want a result?  Yjen you could use stdout as I've shown before:

You use the `WScript.Shell` then pass the command in the `.Exec(ComSpec " /C cscript " command)` method and return the `exec.StdOut.ReadAll()`

I have a working example (using vbs not python) as follows, maybe it helps you:

```
;// The following runs a command (add.vbs) 
;// and retrieves its output via StdOut:

InputBox, x,,"Enter two numbers"
MsgBox % """" RunWaitOne("add.vbs " x) """" ;// result in quotes
ExitApp

RunWaitOne(command)
{
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C cscript /nologo " command)
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

/* This is the external "add.vbs" command:
a=3
b=4
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    a=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    b=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
End If
Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
x=a+b
StdOut.Write x
*/
```

Hth,